# React promise returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, undefined

I have a function that returns an array

```
myfunc: func(){
    myArr = ['hello']
    //does other things

    return myArr;
}
```

at the top I call this function

```
this.myfunc();
    }).then((myArr) => {
      this.setState({myArr: myArr});
      console.log(myArr);
    });
```

Why does myArr get logged as undefined? surely the contents of the returned array should be set in the state in the promise?

As always, I try to post minimal code but can add more.
I am trying to use promises and setState and change that state in react. For some reason it is undefined at this point

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not returning a promise. I think this would work:

```
let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject)) {
    resolve(['hello']);
}

p.then(function(value) {
    setState({key: value});
    console.log(value);
});
```